# ImportError: cannot import name a_class

Tags: django, ipython, pythonanywhere

I have a django site, hosted on pythonanywhere.com. On that site, I can create a Bash console or an iPython console.

I want to be able to do this:

`from my_module import a_class
a_class.object.all()
a_class.object.filter(some_attribute=True)`

If I try to run this inside an iPython conosle, I get the error: `ImportError: cannot import name a_class`

The explanation could be simple, I'm still learning... The answers I found were about third-party module, but this is something I created, and I don't know why it can't be imported. If I don't do `from...import`, I get the error that `a_class` is not defined, as expected.

EDIT

This is my settings.py file:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accueil',
    'a_class',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_site.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_site.wsgi.application'


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

My directory structure is:

    `── a_class
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   │   ├── 0016_auto_20150407_0057.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── a_class
    │   │       ├── home.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── my_site
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py`

Comment: Since you mentioned the answer might be simple: Do you have the manditory `__init__.py` file in your module folder? Does the import work in a non-interactive shell (if so: do you use threading modules and which?)? Is the module somewhere iPython would find it (in the app folder / somewhere in PYTHONPATH)?

Comment: Yes, __init__.py is there. I can import thoses classes from elsewhere in the site, does that answer the second question? The iPython is started from within the root folder of the project.

Comment: Where is my_module in relation to the file structure you show here?

Comment: I should have mentioned in my post that the commands I want to run, they run fine in PyCharm. GilesTomas comment on the answer below helped me get the console I needed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Classes are usually in models, there are a few ways to import them, firstly:

```
from django.apps import apps

MyModel = apps.get_model('app_label', 'ModelName')  # Both strings
```

If it is stored in models.py like it should you could also

```
from myapp.models import Class  # Make sure the app has an __init__.py to be seen
```

Also to use ./manage shell you need to have the app installed and migrated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be honest, I'm not what you mean when you say that the app needs to be installed and migrated. Your first solution gives me this error: ```AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.```, while the second solution gives me a ```ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured.``` error. (Yes, my models are stored in models.py). Hope it clarifies the issue!

Comment: Well in settings.py under INSTALLED_APPS add your app name as a string. Then in the shell run ./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate, please follow the Django polls tutorial if you're just starting out. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: The app is listed in INSTALLED_APPS, and I ran both commands afterwards.

Comment: please post your settings.py and your directory structure

Comment: Just to make sure you picked up on a specific thing that Mikeec3 mentioned -- you need to use `./manage.py shell` to start IPython if you want to access the Django models.  A regular IPython console launched from the PythonAnywhere "Consoles" page won't work, and nor will running "ipython" from a Bash console.   You need to start a Bash console, `cd` to the root directory of your Django project, then run `./manage.py shell`.   Sorry if that was already clear to you, I just thought it needed underlining.

Comment: It needed underlining, @GilesThomas, thank you! I didn't know you had to create the shell this way, and it worked with what you mentioned. I feel a complete answer would emphasis on that point: Mikeec3, you want to edit your answer? IMO my issue was due to a misunderstanding of a pyhtonanywhere feature.

Comment: Glad to help :-)   Just to be clear, the manage.py command is a Django-specific thing rather than a PythonAnywhere thing.  You'd have to run that command wherever you were hosting the app.